# shortcode to display specific recent posts

Tags: shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode to display the top 6 recent posts. The shortcode has to be able to capture a true/false attribute of today though I don't necessarily need this to be able to activate right away. It also has to be able to display the thumbnail, post title, and excerpt. I had it going mostly fine until I added most of the attributes (minus today) and the output setup and that's when I got an error from WordPress. I'm still fairly new to PHP so what I have is a combo of quite a few tips from tutorials on writing shortcodes but I still figure I'm missing something or entered something wrong.

```
function torque_hello_world_shortcode( $atts, $content = null) {
    // set up default parameters
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'num' => '6',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'today' => 'true'
    ), $atts,  );

    $args['today'] = 'true' === $args['today'];

    $output = '';

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post) ;
        $output .='<li><a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'.get_the_title() .' '.get_the_post_thumbnail() .' '.get_the_excerpt() .'</a></li>';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return '<ul>'. $output .'</ul>;
}

add_shortcode ( 'helloworld', 'torque_hello_world_shortcode');
```

Comment: `$args['today'] = 'true' === $args['today'];` that line is the culprit in a quick scan. Your motive is not clear here - what do you want with this?

Comment: I've explained the best I could on what I need it to do. The "today" attribute is supposed to when active allow for [shortcodename today= true] to return true or [shortcodename today = false] to return false when entered in. But also to where the shortcode name on its own would output the title, thumbnail and excerpt of the top 6 recent posts

Comment: There are many issues here: you are mixing shortcode arguments with the `get_posts()` arguments and there where you are screwing things. [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/#parameters) doesn't accept any parameter named `today`. Moreover, True and false should be boolean (without those quotes) and not a string. Not clear about the `return` things you are saying... a function can only `return` once. If you want to say `print/echo` then you can do this easily by adding: `echo true === $args['today'] ? 'Today' : '';`

Comment: And if you're still getting an error from WordPress can you tell us exactly what that error is please?

Comment: The error is "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."